# Dynamic template content with multiple blocks in Meteor Blaze

Tags: html, meteor, meteor-blaze, templating

I understand how to pass in a content block to a template.

```
<template name="myTemplate">
  <div class="container">
    {{> Template.contentBlock }}
  </div>
</template>

{{#myTemplate}}
  <h1> Hey </h1>
{{/myTemplate}}

<!-- results in -->

<div class="container>
  <h1> Hey </h1>
</div>
```

What if there are multiple content blocks I want to be able to specify. Something like:

```
<template name="myTemplate">
  <h1>
    {{> Template.contentBlock_1 }}
  </h1>

  <div class="container">
    {{> Template.contentBlock_2 }}
  </div>

  <div class="footer">
    {{> Template.contentBlock_3 }}
  </div>
</template>
```

And them I'm not sure how that would call that template such that you pass it multiple content blocks.

How does one achieve such behavior with Meteor Blaze?

Comment: You're probably looking for [dynamic templates](http://blazejs.org/api/templates.html#Template-dynamic). Iron-Router and Flow-Router also allow you to pipe multiple templates into a layout at the same time.

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't define the different content blocks as separate templates? That makes it much easier to include any number of them in a parent template.

Comment: I'm failing to understand how you could include more than one content block inside a template declaration in the first place??

Comment: Actually I think I've seen a way of doing this using a type of `switch` statement in Blaze.